# tex1Dfetch and 2D texture

Tags: c++, cuda

If I declare a bindless texture object with

```
cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeLinear;
resDesc.res.linear.devPtr = device_global_memory_ptr;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.f = cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.x = 8 /* 8 bit */ ;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.y = resDesc.res.linear.desc.x;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.z = resDesc.res.linear.desc.x;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.w = resDesc.res.linear.desc.x;
resDesc.res.linear.sizeInBytes = buffer_bytes_size;

cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(texDesc));
texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
texDesc.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
texDesc.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
texDesc.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
texDesc.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeBorder;

cudaTextureObject_t tex1;
cudaCreateTextureObject(&tex1, &resDesc, &texDesc, NULL);
```

and I later use it in the CUDA kernel as

```
uchar4 pixel = tex1Dfetch<uchar4>(tex1, index);
```

will I still get the benefit of a 2D texture caching? Or does the caching depend on the `tex1Dfetch` instruction? I couldn't get the code above to work with `tex2D` unfortunately.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no. "2D" caching would require a correctly pitched allocation, with the width/pitch known to the texture controller. I don't think you can do that in this case.

Comment: @talonmies so should I allocate a buffer with `cudaMallocArray` and do a `cudaMemcpy(device2device)` to that one? I'm going to try this and let you know

Comment: @talonmies That worked. Please make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Provide what as an answer? It seems you abated your own question as an answer and you are in the best position to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope I won't get the benefits of a 2D texture caching.

It won't work if you just use `tex2D` either: I got it working by correctly allocating data with `cudaMallocArray` and then using `tex2D`.